# AWS Lightsail wrapping my html in a frameset

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-lightsail

I am running a docker container inside a aws lightsail instance of ubuntu 18.04. When I curl the docker container from within the aws instance I get a response of:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bibleit.co</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/boots
trap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm
" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6
jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/search.css"/>

</head>
     <body>
       ...
```

But when I curl the url on my local machine i get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bibleit Search</title>  
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://myPublicPort/" frameborder="0" />
</frameset>

</html>
```

This causes all the browsers to display the site in a frame, which I guess by default displays everything in desktop, and wont allow the site to be responsive on mobile.

Does anyone know how to correct this. I cannot find anything on this problem on line.

The URL is http://bibleit.co  if anyone wants to get a response.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lightsail, Ubuntu, Docker, etc., which is probably why you're having difficulty finding am explanation.  It's your DNS provider (Go Daddy, it looks like) that's doing this.

Comment: Thank you are right.
I will look into this from the GoDaddy hosting view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had my GoDaddy domain settings were forwarding and masking my aws static ip which caused my html to be wrapped in a frameset.

So I created a DNS zone on my lightsail network settings, which gave me 4 namespaces.  I then addend those custom namespace to my Godaddy domain settings.

Lightsail automatically uses port 80, so I changed my flask server to use port 80. 
Wallah! No more frameset wrapping.

Thank you